# ShinyApp in R - Contrast Error of having Factor of level 1 with Radiobutton Inputs

Tags: r, shiny

I'm building a Shiny Application using R , basically it takes a dataset and runs it through several models - Classification / Regression.

The problem i am facing now is , I take inputs from the user with some being numeric and some being factors. The Factor inputs always have one level since we are using Radiobuttons to select a value.

```
radioButtons("HomeOwner", "Does the Customer own a home?", choiceNames=c('Yes', 'No'), choiceValues = c(1,0)),
radioButtons("Debt", "Does the Customer has existing debt?", choiceNames=c('Yes', 'No'), choiceValues = c(1,0)),
```

So my dataframe from the building the model has Factors for 3 variables and so does my input data frame from the user but the levels are one since i need to know if they select Yes or No.

Below is the Dataframe :

[image]

[image]

**When i try to predict using the model created , i get the contrast error because of my input dataframe having factor of 1 in three variables , i need them to be factors or is there any way to solve this?**

Edit 1 : Whole App

```
# Application Start

# Initiating Library
source("Functions.R")

library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)



#########################Start of ShinyApp Code#######################################

# Install the shiny and shinythemes packages
# install.packages('shiny')
# install.packages('shinythemes') 

# Create the user interface (ui) where you will take the input and display the output
#ui <- fluidpage()


ui <- fluidPage(shinythemes::themeSelector(),
                titlePanel("Assignment-AIPM"),
                sidebarLayout(
                  sidebarPanel(
                    
                    selectInput("selectds","Select the dataset to work with",
                                choices = c("Boston Housing Dataset"=1,
                                            "Customer Profit Dataset"=2,
                                            "Financial Dataset"=3,
                                            "Education Tech Dataset"=4)
                                            ),
                    br(),
                    actionButton("runmodels","Run Models"),
                    
                  ),
                mainPanel(
                  navbarPage("Information",
                             tabPanel("Input",uiOutput("myInput")),
                             tabPanel("Output",tableOutput("myOutput")),
                             tabPanel("Plots",plotOutput("myPlot"))
                             )
                )
                  
                  
                )
) # fluidPage
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30906325/shiny-use-column-headers-from-read-in-file-as-selectinput-choices - To select
# Input from a datapath using the columns
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54205476/how-to-execute-a-function-in-the-shiny-server-depending-on-the-inputid-value-of/54220548
# Function Execution
# Define server function  
server <- function(input, output, session) 
  {
  observeEvent(input$runmodels,
               {
                 ############################# Boston House Prediction
                 if(input$selectds == 1 )
                   {
                   print("Entering Boston House Prediction Input")
                   output$myInput <- renderUI({
                     tagList(tags$h3("Enter the details of the Land:"),
                             radioButtons("CHAS", "Near Charles River or Not", choiceNames=c('Yes', 'No'), choiceValues = c('1','0')),
                             numericInput("CRIM", "Criminal Rate 1 - 5", 1, min=1, max=5),
                             numericInput("ZN", "Proportion of Land Zone over 25,000 SQFT", 1),
                             numericInput("INDUS", "Proportion of Industrial Business in the town", 1),
                             numericInput("RM", "Average Number of Rooms Per Dwelling", 1),
                             numericInput("NOX", "Tenure in No. of Years", 1),
                             numericInput("AGE", "Proportion of Owner Occupied Buildings prior 1940", 1),
                             numericInput("DIS", "Weighted Distances to Boston Employment Centre", 1),
                             numericInput("RAD", "Radial Access to highways", 1),
                             numericInput("TAX", "Full Value Property rate per 10,000$", 1),
                             numericInput("PTRATIO", "Pupil - Teacher Ratio in Town", 1),
                             numericInput("B", "Proportion of Black Population in Town", 1),
                             numericInput("LSTAT", "Percentage of Lower Status Population", 1),
                             HTML("<br> <br>")
                     )
                   })
                   
                   data_input = reactive({
                     data.frame(CHAS = factor(input$CHAS),
                                CRIM = input$CRIM,
                                ZN = input$ZN,
                                INDUS = input$INDUS,
                                NOX = input$NOX,
                                RM = input$RM,
                                AGE = input$AGE,
                                DIS = input$DIS,
                                RAD = input$RAD,
                                TAX = input$TAX,
                                PTRATIO = input$PTRATIO,
                                B = input$B,
                                LSTAT = input$LSTAT)
                   })
                   
                   regressor_linear <- boston_linear_reg()
                   data_output = reactive({
                     data.frame(Logistic_regression = predict(regressor_linear,type='response',data_input())
                                )
                   })
                   output$myOutput <- renderTable({data_output()})
                 }
                 
                 ############################################### Customer Profit
                 if(input$selectds == 2 )
                 {
                   print("Entering Customer Profit User Input")
                   output$myInput <- renderUI({
                     tagList(tags$h3("Enter the details of the customer:"),
                             radioButtons("Online", "Online Customer?", choiceNames=c('Yes', 'No'), choiceValues = c('1','0')),
                             radioButtons("Age", "Whats your Customer Age Group?", choiceNames=c('0-10','10-20','20-30','30-40','40-50','50-60','60-70'), choiceValues = c('1','2','3','4','5','6','7')),
                             radioButtons("Income", "Whats your Customer Income Group?", choiceNames=c('5k-10k','10k-15k','15k-20k','20k-25k','25k-30k','30k-35k','35k-40k','40k-50k','50k+'), choiceValues = c('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9')),
                             numericInput("Tenure", "Tenure in No. of Years", 1),
                             HTML("<br> <br>"))
                   })
                   
                   data_input = reactive({
                     data.frame(Online = as.integer(input$Online),
                                Age = as.integer(input$Age),
                                Inc = as.integer(input$Income),
                                Tenure = as.numeric(input$Tenure))
                   })
                   
                   regressor_linear <- customer_linear_reg()
                   classifier_Rforest <- customer_RForest_Regression()
                   classifier_NNet <- customer_NeuralNet()
                   
                   data_output = reactive({
                     data.frame(Linear_regression = predict(regressor_linear,data_input()),
                                Random_Forest_Prediction = predict(classifier_Rforest,data_input()),
                                Neural_Net_Prediction = as.data.frame(h2o.predict(classifier_NNet, newdata = as.h2o(data_input())))
                     )
                   })
                   output$myOutput <- renderTable({data_output()})
                 }
                 
                 ########################## Financial set
                 if(input$selectds == 3 )
                 {
                   print("Entering Finanical User Input")
                   output$myInput <- renderUI({
                     tagList(numericInput("Age", "Please enter the Customer Age(1-100)", 25, min=1, max=100),
                             numericInput("Income", "Please enter Customer monthly Income(0-100000$)", 3500, min=0, max=100000),
                             radioButtons("HomeOwner", "Does the Customer own a home?", choiceNames=c('Yes', 'No'), choiceValues = c(1,0)),
                             radioButtons("Debt", "Does the Customer has existing debt?", choiceNames=c('Yes', 'No'), choiceValues = c(1,0)),
                             numericInput("EmpPeriod", "Please enter the Customer employement period in months", 45),
                             numericInput("AccPeriod", "Please enter Customer Account Age in months",45),
                             numericInput("Amount", "Please enter Amount Requested($)",1000),
                             radioButtons("PaySchedule", "Please enter Pay Schedule", choiceNames=c('bi-weekly', 'weekly', 'semi-monthly','monthly'), choiceValues = c(1,2,3,4)),
                             numericInput("CurrAddress", "Please enter the Customer currnt address period in months", 45),
                             numericInput("RiskScore", "Please enter Customer Risk Score (1-100000",40000),
                             numericInput("Enquiry", "Please enter Customer enquiries last month",5),
                             actionButton("Predict", "Predict Sanction"))
                   })
                   
                   observeEvent(input$Predict, {

                     data_input = reactive({
                       data.frame(
                         home_owner = factor(input$HomeOwner),
                         age = as.numeric(input$Age),
                         income = as.numeric(input$Income),
                         has_debt = factor(input$Debt),
                         amount_requested = input$Amount,
                         employment_period = input$EmpPeriod,
                         personal_account_period = input$AccPeriod,
                         pay_schedule = factor(input$PaySchedule),
                         current_address_period = input$CurrAddress,
                         inquiries_last_month = as.integer(input$Enquiry),
                         risk_score = input$RiskScore
                       )
                     })
                     
                     logistic_regressor = financial_logistic_regression()
                     Single_DT = financial_DT()
                     #classifier_svm = financial_svm()
                     
                     str(data_input())
                     data_output = reactive({
                       data.frame(Logistic_regression = predict(logistic_regressor,type='response',newdata=data_input()),
                                  #Support_vector_machine = predict(classifier_svm, type = 'response', newdata = data_input())
                                  Single_Decision_Tree = predict(Single_DT$classifier, type = 'class', newdata = data_input())
                                  
                       )
                     })
                     output$myPlot <- renderPlot({rpart.plot::rpart.plot(Single_DT$classifier)})
                     output$myOutput <- renderTable({data_output()})
                   })        
}
```

Functions.R

```
#Functions for Shiny Assignement
library(caret)
library(ROCR)
library(Metrics)
library(dplyr)
library(caTools)
library(e1071)
library(zoo)
library(car)
library(rpart)
library(randomForest)
library(rpart.plot)
library(h2o)
library(data.table)
# Global Datasets
bostonds <- read.csv('Datasets/02_Boston.csv')
customerds <- read.csv('Datasets/01_CustomerProfit_Regression.csv')
financialds <- read.csv('Datasets/04_P39_Financial_Data.csv')
edtechds <- read.csv('Datasets/05_Lead_Scoring.csv')

boston_linear_reg <- function()
{
  set.seed(1234)
  data_nomiss = bostonds %>% select(CRIM,ZN,INDUS,CHAS,NOX,RM,AGE,DIS,RAD,
                                   TAX,PTRATIO,B,LSTAT,MEDV) %>% na.omit()
  data_nomiss$CHAS = factor(data_nomiss$CHAS)
  regressor_lm = lm(formula = MEDV ~  .,data=data_nomiss)
  
  return(regressor_lm)
  #medv_predict = predict(regressor,test_ds)
  
}








customer_linear_reg <- function() 
{
  data_nomiss = customerds %>% select(Profit,Online,Age,Inc,Tenure) %>% na.omit()
  #data_nomiss$Online = factor(data_nomiss$Online)
  
  set.seed(123)
  regressor_lm = lm(formula = Profit ~ Online + Inc + Age + Tenure 
                 , data = data_nomiss,na.action = na.omit)
  str(data_nomiss)
  return(regressor_lm)
  #profit_predict = predict(regressor, newdata=test_set)
}

customer_RForest_Regression <- function()
{
  ######## Data Processing and Cleanup starts here
  dataset = customerds
  # Creating a new dataset called 'data_nomiss' which will have no missing data
  data_nomiss = dataset %>%  
    select(Profit,Online,Age,Inc,Tenure) %>%
    na.omit()
  
  
  #data_nomiss$Online = factor(data_nomiss$Online)
  #data_nomiss$Age = factor(data_nomiss$Age, labels = c('0-10','10-20','20-30','30-40','40-50','50-60','60-70'),levels = c('1','2','3','4','5','6','7'))
  #data_nomiss$Inc = factor(data_nomiss$Inc, labels = c('5k-10k','10k-15k','15k-20k','20k-25k','25k-30k','30k-35k','35k-40k','40k-50k','50k+'),levels = c('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'))
  # Factor Variables
  
  #data_nomiss[,1] = scale(data_nomiss[,1])
  #data_nomiss[,5] = scale(data_nomiss[,5])
  ########### Data Processing and Cleanup ends here
  
  set.seed(123)
  classifier = randomForest(Profit ~ .,data=data_nomiss,na.action = na.omit,ntree=100)
  return(classifier)
}

customer_NeuralNet <- function() 
{
  dataset = customerds
  data_nomiss = dataset %>%  
    select(Profit,Online,Age,Inc,Tenure) %>%
    na.omit()
  
  set.seed(123)

  h2o.init(nthreads = -1)
  classifier = h2o.deeplearning(y = 'Profit',
                                training_frame = as.h2o(data_nomiss),
                                activation = 'Tanh',
                                hidden = c(10),
                                epochs = 100,
                                train_samples_per_iteration = -2)
  return(classifier)
}
















############################### Financial Dataset

financial_pre_process <- function(ds)
{
  ####################Data Processing and Clean up Start#############################
  data_nomiss = ds %>% select(age,pay_schedule,home_owner,income,
                              months_employed,years_employed,current_address_year,
                              personal_account_m,personal_account_y,has_debt,
                              amount_requested,risk_score,risk_score_2,
                              risk_score_3,risk_score_4,risk_score_5,
                              ext_quality_score,ext_quality_score_2,
                              inquiries_last_month,e_signed) %>% na.omit()
  
  data_nomiss$e_signed = factor(data_nomiss$e_signed)
  
  data_nomiss$home_owner = factor(data_nomiss$home_owner)
  
  data_nomiss$has_debt = factor(data_nomiss$has_debt)
  
  data_nomiss$pay_schedule = factor(data_nomiss$pay_schedule,
                                    levels = c('weekly','bi-weekly','monthly','semi-monthly'),
                                    labels = c(1,2,3,4))
  data_nomiss$employment_period = data_nomiss$months_employed + (data_nomiss$years_employed * 12)
  
  data_nomiss$personal_account_period = data_nomiss$personal_account_m + (data_nomiss$personal_account_y * 12)
  
  data_nomiss$current_address_period = data_nomiss$current_address_year * 12
  data_nomiss = select(data_nomiss,-c(months_employed,years_employed,personal_account_m,personal_account_y,current_address_year))
  data_nomiss[,1] = scale(data_nomiss[,1]) # Age
  data_nomiss[,4] = scale(data_nomiss[,4]) # Income
  data_nomiss[,6:14] = scale(data_nomiss[,6:14]) # Amount Requested -> Risk score
  data_nomiss[,16:18] = scale(data_nomiss[,16:18]) # Created Columns
  data_nomiss[,1] = apply(data_nomiss[,1], 1, as.numeric)
  data_nomiss[,4] = apply(data_nomiss[,4], 1, as.numeric)
  return(data_nomiss)
  
  ####################Data Processing and Clean up End#############################
}
financial_logistic_regression <- function()
{
  ds = financialds
  set.seed(1234)
  data_nomiss = financial_pre_process(ds)
  str(data_nomiss)
  classifier_log = glm(formula = e_signed ~ age+pay_schedule+current_address_period+home_owner+income+employment_period+has_debt+amount_requested+personal_account_period+risk_score+inquiries_last_month,
                   family = binomial,
                   data = data_nomiss)
  return(classifier_log)
}
financial_svm <- function()
{
  ds = financialds
  set.seed(1234)
  data_nomiss = financial_pre_process(ds)
  classifier_svm = svm(formula = e_signed ~ age+pay_schedule+current_address_period+home_owner+income+employment_period+has_debt+amount_requested+personal_account_period+risk_score+inquiries_last_month,
                   data = data_nomiss,
                   type = 'C-classification',
                   kernel = 'radial')
  return(classifier_svm)
  
}
financial_DT <- function()
{
  ds = financialds
  set.seed(1234)
  data_nomiss = financial_pre_process(ds)
  classifier_DT = rpart(formula = e_signed ~ age+pay_schedule+current_address_period+home_owner+income+employment_period+has_debt+amount_requested+personal_account_period+risk_score+inquiries_last_month,
                     data = data_nomiss)
  result <- list()
  result$classifier <- classifier_DT
  result$plot <- rpart.plot::rpart.plot(classifier_DT)
  return(result)
  
}
financial_RForest <- function()
{
  ds = financialds
  set.seed(1234)
  data_nomiss = financial_pre_process(ds)
  classifier_RForest = randomForest(x= training_set[-15],
                            y= training_set$e_signed,
                            ntree=1500)
  result <- list()
  result$classifier <- classifier_RForest
  result$plot <- rpart.plot::rpart.plot(classifier_RForest)
  return(result)
  
}
}
```

Comment: We would need to see the whole app to try to debug the problem.

Comment: @DaveArmstrong Edited , Let me know , i tried breaking my head on this , not getting any ideas to solve this.

Comment: Could you post a link to the datasets so we could run the app?  I've got an idea about what the problem is, but I want to verify before I post an answer.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1GmIYB6KbenXkQD8wOoKPskc0o8dUkn4j?usp=sharing 
@DaveArmstrong

Comment: @DaveArmstrong were you able to figure it out? I'm still stuck with it :(.

Comment: I needed to request permission to the google drive folder, which I did, but I didn't get an e-mail saying permission was granted.

Comment: @DaveArmstrong Its done. Check now?

Comment: I'm working on a mac using R 4.0.3 and shiny 1.5.0 and I don't get the same error that you get.  It seems to always predict a value of 1 for both single DT and logistic regression. There are a couple of problems I can spot.  First, you're not using the variable `e_signed` in the input fields and so your prediction dataset won't have all of the right values.  The other problem is that the input into the model has standardized all of the continuous variables, but you're having people input raw values into the fields. ... continued

Comment: These raw values will need to be transformed into the standardized scores to be able to generate appropriate predictions from the model.

Comment: @DaveArmstrong , I was standardizing all the input from user but i kept getting the contrast error having only 1 factor level to input into the model. I am trying to predict E_signed using the user input. User inputs the other variables involved in predicting E_signed.